# Setup git locally on filesystem

Tags: git

I am stuggling to understand how to set this up correctly. I want to be able to have a test site and a production site and use git to manage it.

my current file system looks like this (production is in the www folder and test is within the www in a folder called test

```
-www
  -test
    index.html
index.html
```

Right now I have it setup so i can make changes on test and commit them with git but I dont know how to push or pull them into www/

Comment: It's not clear what you mean here.  If there is a git repository under `test` then those changes are already under `www`.  Do you mean you modify `www/test/index.html` and now want those changes in `www/index.html`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesting `test` under your production site sounds bad. It would be better to organize this way:

```
site/
├── repo.git
├── test
└── www
```

Here, `repo.git` is a *bare git repository*, and you could have it as the remote of both `www` and `test`. Then you could push and pull from whichever.

You could convert your existing setup with these commands:

```
cd test
git clone --bare . ../repo.git
git remote add origin ../repo.git
cd ..
mv www www.bak
git clone repo.git www
```

In this setup, you could push in `test`, and then you could pull in `www`.

Comment: This was very helpful, I now have a much better set up directory ( I had to do it how it was before because of my shared host) and I have a working test environment with git push/pull to prod!! Thank you so much!